# Finding decompress algorithm for unknown compression

Tags: file-format, decompress

I have a raw data of what seems to be a compressed PNG file and I need to find the decompress algorithm for unknown compression.
You can see the file [here](https://hexed.it#base64: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).
I think they are using some kind of LZRW 1 with some strange dictionary build routine.

I succeed to de-compress the `IHeader` of the file correctly (I verified it with CRC).
This the comparing between them:
[image]

This is the algorithm it worked with:
[image]

There is a 1 byte flag every each 8 bytes.
If the flag is > 0 I am checking its bits.
For example:
`08 (0000 1000) 00 00 02 58 (00 83) 5A 08 06`

The flag is `08` => `0000 1000`
So it need to go 5 step forward after the flag => `00 83` ....

The dictionary looks to be built by 2 bytes, for example: `00 83`
In binary:
`0000 0000 1000 0011`

The first 4 bits from the right are might be the length and the rest (12 bits) are probably the absolute offset.
offset length
`(0000 0000 1000) (0011)`

I looked to the next flags after the first chunk dictionary (`0x0 0x83`) and saw a new dictionaries (`0x9 0x84`) but it doesn't work well:
[image]

This is the "best" result I received with my algorithm:
[image]

My algorithm pseudo-code:

```
data = readFile(filePath)
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    controlbits = data[i] // controlbits is 8 bites
    i += 1
    for bit in controlbits:
        if bit == 0:
            output += data[i]
            i += 1
        else: // bit is 1
            // Example: data[i] = 0x0, data[i+1] = 0x83
            // data[i] = 0000 0000
            // data[i+1] = 1000 0011
            // dict = 0000 0000 1000 0011
            dict = data[i] << 8
            dict |=  data[i+1]


            offset = dict[0:12]
            len = dict[12:16]
            output += output[offset: offset+len]
            i += 2
```

I gave a link in the beginning for the full file content but you also have here 570 bytes from the file:

```
0000-0010:  00 89 50 4e-47 0d 0a 1a-0a 00 00 00-00 0d 49 48  ..PNG... ......IH
0000-0020:  44 52 08 00-00 02 58 00-83 5a 08 06-80 00 83 64  DR....X. .Z.....d
0000-0030:  31 28 fe 00-00 21 00 c7-49 44 41 54-78 9c ed 00  1(...!.. IDATx...
0000-0040:  dd 79 54 14-57 fa 37 f0-00 6f 2f ac-22 8d a2 20  .yT.W.7. .o/."...
0000-0050:  41 00 40 82-4b 5c 23 2e-e8 24 00 ae-e8 88 1a b5  A.@.K\#. .$......
0000-0060:  d1 38 81 00-18 46 09 82-26 26 18 67-00 8c fa 33  .8...F.. &&.g...3
0000-0070:  a2 a2 a3 31-06 00 c6 2d-1a 15 63 3c-2a d1 00 18  ...1...- ..c<*...
0000-0080:  25 c6 65 cc-28 51 8f 00-21 6a 30 1a-11 a2 a0 c6  %.e.(Q.. !j0.....
0000-0090:  00 05 d4 38-80 2c 8d 46-a1 00 e9 a6-de 3f 3c f4  ...8.,.F .....?<.
0000-00a0:  4b 2d 00 dd-54 77 57 43-8b cf e7 00-1c ce a1 aa  K-..TwWC ........
0000-00b0:  6e df ba d5-00 b5 3d 5d-f7 d6 bd 32-86 00 61 18  n.....=] ...2..a.
0000-00c0:  10 42 08 21-84 10 02 c9-c8 1b bb 00-84 09 84 4d  .B.!.... .......M
0000-00d0:  08 0d 05 58-84 09 84 12-a3 00 41 8b-09 84 44 62  ...X.... ..A...Db
0000-00e0:  14 60 11 09-94 08 48 8c-02 2c 09 95-89 51 80 42  .`....H. .,...Q.B
0000-00f0:  45 09 a4 22-31 0a b0 09-a4 42 08 24-46 01 16 09  E.."1... .B.$F...
0000-0100:  b3 42 88 c4-09 28 c0 22-84 09 83 91-18 0a 63 ff  .B...(." ......c.
0000-0110:  09 84 0a 94-09 84 0a d5-09 94 0b 24-09 95 0b 64  ........ ...$...d
0000-0120:  fe 09 a4 0b-a4 09 a4 0b-e5 09 b3 0c-37 09 83 91  ........ ....7...
0000-0130:  7f 18 0a 63-09 84 0a 94-09 84 0a d5-09 94 0b 24  ...c.... .......$
0000-0140:  ff 09 95 0b-64 09 a4 0b-a4 09 a4 0b-e5 09 b3 0c  ....d... ........
0000-0150:  37 80 09 83-91 98 52 ea-0c 1f 3f 00-7e 8c 07 0f  7.....R. ..?.~...
0000-0160:  1e a0 b2 b2-00 12 1e 1e-1e 68 d9 b2-25 00 94 4a  ........ .h..%..J
0000-0170:  c9 57 d3 24-65 66 00 66-e2 f4 e9 d3-b8 7b f7 00  .W.$ef.f .....{..
0000-0180:  2e 34 1a 0d-00 60 eb d6-00 ad 8d 5c-2a 22 25 3a  .4...`.. ...\*"%:
0000-0190:  3f 00 08 21-f6 aa b4 b4-14 a9 00 a9-a9 d0 68 34  ?..!.... ......h4
0000-01a0:  18 37 6e 00-1c 5e 7e f9-e5 c6 2e 92-00 64 0a 0a  .7n..^~. .....d..
0000-01b0:  0a b0 68 d1-22 00 38 38-38 40 a5 52-a1 43 00 87  ..h.".88 8@.R.C..
0000-01c0:  0e 18 3c 78-30 5e 7a 00-e9 25 9b ad-53 c6 30 0c  ..<x0^z. .%..S.0.
0000-01d0:  00 63 6d 26-85 85 85 d8-b0 00 61 03-d2 d2 d2 90  .cm&.... ..a.....
0000-01e0:  97 97 00 87-9a 9a 1a c3-32 85 42 00-81 4e 9d 3a  ........ 2.B..N.:
0000-01f0:  61 e9 d2 a5-01 78 fd f5-d7 59 9f 1b-11 33 00 ae  a....x.. .Y...3..
0000-0200:  5d bb 66 32-ef bf fd 00-ed 6f f8 d7-bf fe 65 6d  ].f2.... .o....em
0000-0210:  00 11 ed da-d9 b3 67 31-7d 00 fa 74-e4 e4 e4 b0  ......g1 }..t....
0000-0220:  e6 2b 00 14-0a e8 74 3a-ab f3 1f 00-38 70 20 8a  .+....t: ....8p..
0000-0230:  8b 8b 0d d3-00 cb 96 2d-c3 c4 89 13-ad 00 ce 97  .......- ........
0000-0240:  88 63 e9 f9-41 48 00 53-b1 62 c5 0a-6c df be 00  .c..AH.S .b..l...
0000-0250:  dd 30 fd ca-2b af e0 cb-00 2f bf 6c-c4 12 11 ae  .0..+... ./.l....
0000-0260:  a2 00 a2 22-04 07 07 e3-8f 3f 80 01-a3 28 95 4a  ...".... .?...(.J
0000-0270:  7c f7 dd 77-00 78 ed b5-d7 1a bc 2c-fb 00 f7 ef  |..w.x.. ...,....
0000-0280:  c7 fc f9 f3-0d d3 00 ad-5b b7 46 46-46 86 55 00  ........ [.FFF.U.
0000-0290:  79 66 65 65-21 38 38 98-00 37 ff af-7f fd 2b b6  yfee!88. .7....+.
0000-02a0:  6c 00 d9 82-80 80 00 ab-f2 17 00 62-f5 4f e7 a3  l....... ...b.O..
0000-02b0:  47 8f 62 00-d2 a4 49 28-2d 2d 15 5c-00 ae d7 eb  G.b...I( --.\....
0000-02c0:  71 e5 ca 15-5c 00 bf 7e-9d b7 ec e6-cd 9b 00 b8  q...\..~ ........
0000-02d0:  7a f5 aa c9-fc ef df 20-bf 6f 17 33-5a 46 46 06  z....... .o.3ZFF.
0000-02e0:  86 00 0f 1f-0e ad 56 6b-b3 75 a0 21-23 1d 14 03  ......Vk .u.!#...
0000-02f0:  86 e9 f2 f2-72 00 9b ad-ab a1 dd be-7d 1b 00 27  ....r... ....}..'
0000-0300:  4e 9c 40 68-68 28 da 00-b5 6b d7 d8-c5 e1 b1 e6  N.@hh(.. .k......
0000-0310:  10 fc 78 56-23 c4 f7 ee-dd 43 00 71-71 31 b4 5a  ..xV#... .C.qq1.Z
0000-0320:  2d dc dd 00-dd 11 10 10-80 f6 ed db-00 c3 c1 c1  -....... ........
0000-0330:  a1 d1 cb 66-cf 02 c7 8b-bd 97 cf 52-14 03 ac 00  ...f.... ...R....
0000-0340:  6b 7d db b6-6d 1b b1 34-00 44 c8 fa-f5 eb 0d c1  k}..m..4 .D......
0000-0350:  15 40 00 18-63 24 26 26-36 4a 80 00-a5 d1 68 58  .@..c$&& 6J....hX
0000-0360:  c7 8b 2d ef-00 59 e9 e9-e9 08 09 09-c1 00 85 0b  ..-..Y.. ........
0000-0370:  17 24 3f 2e-ad 6a 00 83-95 9d 9d 8d-f1 e3 c7 00  .$?..j.. ........
0000-0380:  1b bd 79 10-d3 f4 7a 3d-00 a2 a3 a3-79 c1 55 bb  ..y...z= ....y.U.
0000-0390:  76 00 ed 30-62 c4 08 7a-a2 61 00 44-69 69 29 e2  v..0b..z .a.Dii).
0000-03a0:  e2 e2 10 00-14 14 84 c0-c0 40 4c 9d-00 3a 15 77  ........ .@L..:.w
0000-03b0:  ef de 6d ec-62 00 f1 3c-4f e7 c7 ef-bf ff 00 8e  ..m.b..< O.......
0000-03c0:  19 33 66 20-30 30 10 00-81 81 81 18-30 60 00 c6  .3f.00.. ....0`..
0000-03d0:  00 8f 1f 8f-88 88 08 8c-1a 00 35 0a-5d ba 74 81  ........ ..5.].t.
0000-03e0:  4a a5 40 42-24 43 16 2f-5e 8c c7 8f-00 1f 37 58  J.@B$C./ ^.....7X
0000-03f0:  d9 ec fd 78-b1 00 f7 f2-d9 9b e4 e4-64 38 00 3b  ...x.... ....d8.;
0000-0400:  3b 1b fe ba-76 ed 6a 00-32 bd 46 a3-61 a5 77 76  ;...v.j. 2.F.a.wv
0000-0410:  00 76 c6 c9-93 27 1b a8-b4 00 cf 8e-ba 3f c2 6b  .v...'.. .....?.k
0000-0420:  fd ef 04 7f-ff 13 fd f9-29 d3 9a b5-00 5f 1a 9a  ........ )...._..
0000-0430:  87 87 07 5e-7f 00 fd 75-0c 1e 3c 18-5e 5e 00 5e  ...^...u ..<.^^.^
0000-0440:  ac 65 45 45-45 98 39 00-73 a6 e4 eb-b4 ea 09 d6  .eEEE.9. s.......
0000-0450:  00 9c 39 73-f0 e4 c9 13-d6 40 bc 12-b3 22 26 26  ..9s.... .@..."&&
0000-0460:  06 7e 7e 00-7e a8 a8 a8-40 51 51 11-00 ae 5c b9  .~~.~... @QQ...\.
0000-0470:  22 f8 6b 6c-c6 00 8c 19-28 2a 2a 62-cd 4b 00 49  ".kl.... (**b.K.I
0000-0480:  49 69 f2 4f-ad 6a 1d 00-3b 76 0c 37-6f de 34 4c  Ii.O.j.. ;v.7o.4L
0000-0490:  08 3b 3a 3a-62 25 33 98-30 61 00 42-23 96 ca fe  .;::b%3. 0a.B#...
0000-04a0:  15 15 15 00-e1 8b 2f be-68 ec 62 d4-00 cb da f3  ....../. h.b.....
0000-04b0:  e3 59 a0 d5-6a 00 31 7b-f6 6c 6c da-b4 a9 00 de  .Y..j.1{ .ll.....
0000-04c0:  ea ec 27 4f-9e e0 e4 02-c9 93 38 79-f2 24 2c 93  ..'O.... ..8y.$,.
0000-04d0:  e0 00 ea ea-da 20 65 b4-f7 e3 00 c5-de cb 67 6f  ......e. ......go
0000-04e0:  74 3a 1d 00-aa aa aa 0c-d3 75 ff 17-00 c2 30 0c  t:...... .u....0.
0000-04f0:  2f 8d 5e af-b7 00 49 d9-9e 65 61 61-61 48 00 49  /.^...I. .eaaaH.I
0000-0500:  49 61 cd 1b-35 6a 94 02-e8 cf 57 57-57 9b 34 23  Ia..5j.. ..WWW.4#
0000-0510:  5a 80 2b b3-b0 6f df 3e-00 40 4d 10-4d 0d fe 33  Z.+..o.> .@M.M..3
0000-0520:  a3 63 ee dc-b9 00 86 e5-07 0e 1c c0-fd fb 00 f7  .c...... ........
0000-0530:  e1 e3 e3 23-d9 3a 2d 00-0e b0 4a 4a-4a f0 c3 0f  ...#.:-. ..JJJ...
0000-0540:  00 3f b0 e6-4d 9b 36 0d-9b 00 37 6f-16 9d c7 8c  .?..M.6. ..7o....
0000-0550:  19 33 00 78-f3 0e 1f 3e-fc dc 04 00-58 a7 4f 9f  .3.x...> ....X.O.
0000-0560:  66 4d c7 c7-00 c7 53 70-d5 44 48 71-7e 20 d8 bb  fM....Sp .DHq~...
```

Comment: Pretty sure you've thought of this but do you have other examples of the compression? Maybe a plain text, XML files or something that isn't compressed to start with. It'd make it easier to guess how the dictionary is built then.

Comment: Unfortunately not because it was a part of a CTF and the challenge is to figure out the decompression algorithm without knowing the compression. You need to figure it out just by looking on the compressed image. The PNG has a standard header so it should be the clue, because I already showed how I figure out the origin header but we need to do it also on the data.